# not able to delete all the children of an element with specific class

Tags: javascript, html

So, I was trying to delete all the children of an element lets say `wrapper` that has `aurl` class, and wrote this code

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){
 document.getElementById("reload").addEventListener("click", function (){
  var w = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  for(var i=0; i<w.children.length; i++){
   if(w.children[i].classList.contains("aurl")){
    w.removeChild(w.children[i]);
   }
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="reload">
   <span>Reload</span>
   </div>
   <div class="aurl" id="one">
   One
   </div>
   <div class="aurl" id="two">
   Two
   </div>
   <div class="aurl" id="three">
   Three
   </div>
   <div class="aurl" id="four">
   Four
   </div>
   <div class="aurl" id="five">
   Five
   </div>
   <div class="aurl" id="six">
   Six
   </div>
  </div>
```

when I click on the reload button only `one`, `three`, `five` elements are being deleted and rest are not.
Here is my observation after debugging the code, for `i=4` value of `e` is `undefined` and its getting the alternate elements every time e.g. one, three, five to delete.

Comment: what is e inside removechild(e)?

Comment: You are changing the array as you loop through it, which is a classic bug in javascript. Looping backwards is one fix.

Comment: its `w.children[i]` @FahadNisar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run the for Loop reverse, because the children.length decreases.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){
 document.getElementById("reload").addEventListener("click", function (){
  var w = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  for(var i=w.children.length-1; i>=0; i--){
   if(w.children[i].classList.contains("aurl")){
    w.removeChild(w.children[i]);
   }
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="reload">
   <span>Reload</span>
   </div>
   <div class="aurl" id="one">
   One
   </div>
   <div class="aurl" id="two">
   Two
   </div>
   <div class="aurl" id="three">
   Three
   </div>
   <div class="aurl" id="four">
   Four
   </div>
   <div class="aurl" id="five">
   Five
   </div>
   <div class="aurl" id="six">
   Six
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` and `forEach` to remove element.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){ document.getElementById("reload").addEventListener("click", function (){
  var children = document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper .aurl');
  var parent = document.getElementById('wrapper');

  Array.from(children).forEach(function(child){
    parent.removeChild(child);
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="reload">
    <span>Reload</span>
  </div>
  <div class="aurl" id="one">
  One
  </div>
  <div class="aurl" id="two">
  Two
  </div>
  <div class="aurl" id="three">
  Three
  </div>
  <div class="aurl" id="four">
  Four
  </div>
  <div class="aurl" id="five">
  Five
  </div>
  <div class="aurl" id="six">
  Six
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `childNodes` AS following explanation

The difference between `childNodes` and `children`, which is that childNodes contains all `nodes`, including `text nodes` consisting entirely of `whitespace`, while `children` is a collection of just the child nodes that are elements.

I think it may helped you

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution here, just pass the element/class you want to delete from the container

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){
    document.getElementById("reload").addEventListener("click", function (){
        var container = document.getElementById("wrapper");
        var elements = container.getElementsByClassName("aurl");

        while (elements[0]) {
            elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nhbevhL8/1/) is a JSFiddle demo of it.